# Dot matrix printer on Windows 10 using USB-to-parallel cable not working as expected

Tags: windows, usb, printer, parallel-port, dot-matrix-printer

I'm trying to connect an OKI microline 3390 24-pin dot matrix printer to a windows 10 laptop, mainly to print PDFs. The printer only has a centronics 36-pin parallel port and the laptop only a USB one, so I use a (bidirectional) usb-to-parallel cable.
When I plug in the cable, unconnected to the printer:

- A device called "USB2.0-Print" shows up under unspecified in the "Devices and Printers" part of the control panel.
- Two new devices show up in the device manager under "Universal Serial Bus controllers": "No Printer Attached" and "USB Printing Support". The latter has a property "Bus relations" pointing to USB002.

I installed the correct driver using some OKI utility so adding a printer, choosing the driver and manually pointing it to USB002 is no hassle, however, when I try to print a test page, nothing happens; the page just gets the status "Printing", and the printer does nothing at all. My printer has a hex-dump mode, and it does not even seem to receive any data. I tried pointing the printer to other ports as well, to the same effect, though some of them give errors.

(And yes, the SEL-light is on.)

What am I missing?

Comment: That would be a fairly old printer for Windows 10. Try uninstalling the driver you have, restart, and then add the printer in Control Panel, Devices and Printers.  See if that works.

Comment: As the printer is sure to understand plain text, try connecting it to the Generic/Text Only driver. Also, to uninstall, you need to remove the drivers from Print Server Properties.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Sadly, they do not work; the printer still does not seem to receive anything.

Comment: Have you been able to test the printer on any other system, or conversely, test a different similar printer on yours?

Comment: What model is the adapter cable? Does it come with any s/w?

Comment: The seller had it running on windows 10, using a similar set-up, however, I cannot contact him anymore. I had not tried my computer with this type of printer. The cable is this one: [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000038793897.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.7f06fa5cy2VaMd&algo_pvid=1b6d9b6e-8056-4a45-81c0-a7047fd3977c&algo_exp_id=1b6d9b6e-8056-4a45-81c0-a7047fd3977c-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000016577999081%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21EUR%215.35%213.99%21%21%211.07%21%21%40210318cf16658582457367173ecb99%2112000016577999081%21sea&curPageLogUid=onI3hpAxAQpL). There was no s/w.